# Which software to use for designing city plans?

Tags: cartography, design

Which software would you suggest I use for designing city plans? The result needs to be an image (jpeg) so georeferencing is not necessary. I have options like ArcGIS, AdobeInDesign, Adobe Illustrator. I don't know which software is the best for maps like these in example: [image]

Also, I would need to add some 2d effects on the buildings.

Comment: What kind of input data will you be working with? (File formats)

Comment: I would just drawing all over again because of the bad resolution of source image.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a combination of programs. Your existing data is most likely in either shapefiles or autocad files so you can use those as a base. One option is to export those files to an Adobe Illustrator file (AI) which is then used to create good looking graphics. For the effect on the buildings, use 'drop shadow' in AI; it works great.